# Two drawer cabinet with one door open safety feature, is stuck with top drawer open

Tags: cabinets

Top drawer of 2 Drawer cabinet is stuck because object fell out of drawer in open space between cabinets.
I cant reach the object; the object is a portable plastic computer desk about 14×8.
The drawer below cant be open because of safety feature.
I cant see the object but knows its the portable desk.

Comment: Can try bending something like a cloths hanger or a piece of wire and popping it up/over/down.

Comment: Not really a home improvement question, but I can't think of anywhere better it could be put.

Comment: Pictures please.

Comment: Is this a standalone cabinet or is it fixed to the wall with a countertop over it? Do you have access and can you remove the back?

Comment: Can you turn the cabinet upside down, potentially allowing the object to fall back "up?"  (Obvs remove any lower drawers, or at least the stuff in them!)